# Deep-Cloning an object using Object.fromEntries()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

Sometime ago, I read about the proposal of the new method [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) that is supported on newer versions of some browsers ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility)). While reading about it, I had in mind the idea of use this method to `deep-clone` an `object` in replacement of using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`. So far, I have come with the next recursive approach that from my point of view appears to work.

```js
const obj = {
  key1: {key11: "key11", key12: "key12", key13: {key131: 22}},
  key2: {key21: "key21", key22: "key22"},
  key3: "key3",
  key4: [1,2,3,4]
}

const cloneObj = (obj) =>
{
    if (typeof obj !== "object")
       return obj;
    else if (Array.isArray(obj))
       return obj.slice();

    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(
        ([k,v]) => ([k, cloneObj(v)])
    ));
}

// Clone the original object.
let newObj = cloneObj(obj);

// Make changes on the original object.
obj.key1.key11 = "TEST";
obj.key3 = "TEST";
obj.key1.key13.key131 = "TEST";
obj.key4[1] = "TEST";

// Display both objects on the console.
console.log("Original object: ", obj);
console.log("Cloned object: ", newObj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, I'm in doubt if I'm not missing something to accomplish the `deep-clone` of an object. So my questions are:

**1)** I'm missing something important in order to accomplish the `deep-clone` of an object?

**2)** In the case the approach is all right, do you believe this can performs better than using `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`?

Thanks in advance!

---

## Update 1

Here is the updated version with the feedback provided on the answers:

```js
const obj = {
  key1: {key11: "key11", key12: "key12", key13: {key131: 22}},
  key2: {key21: "key21", key22: "key22"},
  key3: "key3",
  key4: [1,2,3,{key: "value"}]
}

const cloneObj = (obj) =>
{
    if (Object(obj) !== obj)
       return obj;
    else if (Array.isArray(obj))
       return obj.map(cloneObj);

    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(
        ([k,v]) => ([k, cloneObj(v)])
    ));
}

// Clone the original object.
let newObj = cloneObj(obj);

// Make changes on the original object.
obj.key1.key11 = "TEST";
obj.key3 = "TEST";
obj.key1.key13.key131 = "TEST";
obj.key4[1] = "TEST";
obj.key4[3].key = "TEST";

// Display both objects on the console.
console.log("Original object: ", obj);
console.log("Cloned object: ", newObj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

## Update 2

Added a performance comparison in relation to my second question:

```
Tested on Firefox 66.0.3 (64bits):
Test_JSON: 1923.000ms
Test_cloneObj: 2047.000ms

Tested on Chrome 73.0.3683.103 (64 bits):
Test_JSON: 2276.560ms
Test_cloneObj: 1903.675ms
```

```js
const cloneObj = (obj) =>
{
    if (Object(obj) !== obj)
       return obj;
    else if (Array.isArray(obj))
       return obj.map(cloneObj);

    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(
        ([k,v]) => ([k, cloneObj(v)])
    ));
}

// Generate an object.

const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

let obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    obj["Array" + i] = Array.from({length: 100}, () => getRandom(0, 1000));
    obj["Obj" + i] = {"key": getRandom(0, 1000)};
    obj["Const" + i] = "some_string";
}

// Test performance on JSON.parse()/stringify()

console.time("Test_JSON");
let obj1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.timeEnd("Test_JSON");

// Test performance on cloneObj().

console.time("Test_cloneObj");
let obj2 = cloneObj(obj);
console.timeEnd("Test_cloneObj");
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one thing:

```
else if (Array.isArray(obj))
  return obj.slice();
```

This will return a shallow copy of the array. If the array contains objects, those underlying objects will not be cloned:

```js
const obj = [
  ['foo']
];

const cloneObj = (obj) =>
{
    if (typeof obj !== "object")
       return obj;
    else if (Array.isArray(obj))
       return obj.slice();

    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(
        ([k,v]) => ([k, cloneObj(v)])
    ));
}

// Clone the original object.
let newObj = cloneObj(obj);

// Make changes on the original object.
obj[0][0] = 'bar';

// Display both objects on the console.
console.log("Original object: ", obj);
console.log("Cloned object: ", newObj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

To fix it, `return obj.map(cloneObj);` instead:

```js
const obj = [
  ['foo']
];

const cloneObj = (obj) =>
{
    if (typeof obj !== "object")
       return obj;
    else if (Array.isArray(obj))
       return obj.map(cloneObj);

    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(
        ([k,v]) => ([k, cloneObj(v)])
    ));
}

// Clone the original object.
let newObj = cloneObj(obj);

// Make changes on the original object.
obj[0][0] = 'bar';

// Display both objects on the console.
console.log("Original object: ", obj);
console.log("Cloned object: ", newObj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was sure I was missing something important!

Answer (score 1):

1. The deep-cloning is fine, as deeply nested objects still retain their properties - however, arrays need to be cloned too; replaced `obj.slice()` with `obj.map(o => cloneObj(o))`.
2. This method is actually *faster* than `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` - three tests on [JSBench](http://jsbench.me) and `JSON` was slower by more than 10% every single time.

Comment: What browser did you run the check on? `cloneObj` runs notably faster for me as well on Chrome 73, but I don't have FF 63 installed unfortunately. It may be implementation-dependent.

Comment: I ran it on the latest Chrome @CertainPerformance (`Object.fromEntries` doesn't work on Safari).

Comment: Thanks for your help too. I really don't have too much faith on the performance, since the existence of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074) thread says `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` is better. However, it is good to know it can work.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, your arrays are not deep-cloned - use `obj.map(cloneObj)` instead of  `obj.slice()`.

But another oversight is `typeof obj !== "object"`, which doesn't work for `null`. Better use `Object(obj) !== obj`.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution!