# Filter / reduce nested object recursively

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, filter

I have a deeply nested object that I need to search to remove certain keys. The keys to remove are stored in an array indicated in the `removeKeys` array.
Currently, the function only filters the top level object but scales the rest fine, it just does not filter child objects. How would I reduce the full object properly to get the desired output?

The initial unfiltered object:

```
let item = {
            "label": "test",
            "id": "test",
            "styles": {
                "label": "Styles",
                "styles": {
                    "test": {
                        "test": "test",
                        "label": "test",
                        "test1": {
                            "label": "test",
                            "image": {
                                "label": "test",
                                "type": "test",
                                "value": "test",
                                "autoSelect": "",
                                "id": ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "test": {
                "label": "test",
                "test": []
            }
        }
```

The keys to remove from the object:

```
const removeKeys = ["label", "type", "autoSelect"];
```

The recursive function to filter the nested object:

```
let filterObject = filterNestObject(item);

function filterNestObject(item) {
  return Object.keys(item)
  .filter(key => {
    if (typeof item[key] === 'object') filterNestObject(item[key]);

    if (!removeKeys.includes(key)) return true;

    return false 
  })  
  .reduce((object, key) => {
    return {
      ...object,
      [key]: item[key]
    };
  }, {});

}
```

The expected result would be:

```
{
            "id": "test",
            "styles": {
                "styles": {
                    "test": {
                        "test": "test",
                        "test1": {
                            "image": {
                                "value": "test",
                                "id": ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "test": {
                "test": []
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago, I made an attempt to create a `cloneObj()` method to deep-clone an object using the new proposal [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). You can check, for reference, the question I made in that moment on next link: [Deep-Cloning an object using Object.fromEntries()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700810/deep-cloning-an-object-using-object-fromentries)

I believe this method can be slightly modified to suit your goals:

```js
const item = {"label": "test","id": "test","styles": {"label": "Styles","styles": {"test": {"test": "test","label": "test","test1": {"label": "test","image": {"label": "test","type": "test","value": "test","autoSelect": "","id": ""}}}}},"test": {"label": "test","test": [{label: "foo", test: "test4"}]}};
const removeKeys = ["label", "type", "autoSelect"];

const cloneObjWithoutKeys = (obj, keys) =>
{
    if (Object(obj) !== obj)
       return obj;
    else if (Array.isArray(obj))
       return obj.map(o => cloneObjWithoutKeys(o, keys));

    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj)
              .filter(([k, v]) => !keys.includes(k))
              .map(([k, v]) => ([k, cloneObjWithoutKeys(v, keys)])
    ));
}

console.log(cloneObjWithoutKeys(item, removeKeys));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note, this will also traverse inner arrays of objects to filter out the desired keys.

Comment: This was the only solution that did not convert the array to an object. Thank you for assuming the edge case.

Comment: Thanks, but you should note that `Object.fromEntries()` is not well supported right now.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake in your code is that you do the recursive call in the `filter` callback. But there you lose the object returned from the recursive call. Instead make it in the `reduce` callback.

A minor correction: to test whether a value is an object it is not enough to do `typeof item[key] === "object"` as `null` would also pass that test. Here is the adapted code:

```js
function filterNestObject(item) {
    return Object.keys(item)
        .filter(key => !removeKeys.includes(key))  
        .reduce((acc, key) => {
            return Object.assign(acc, {
              [key]: Object(item[key]) === item[key] ? filterNestObject(item[key]) : item[key]
            });
        }, Array.isArray(item) ? [] : {});
}

const item = {"label": "test","id": "test","styles": {"label": "Styles","styles": {"test": {"test": "test","label": "test","test1": {"label": "test","image": {"label": "test","type": "test","value": "test","autoSelect": "","id": ""}}}}},"test": {"label": "test","test": []}};
const removeKeys = ["label", "type", "autoSelect"];
const filterObject = filterNestObject(item);
console.log(filterObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky and not very performant so it may not be a good solution if you're dealing with very large object graphs, but here's a one-liner solution using the `replacer` callback in [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(audience, (k, v) => removeKeys.includes(k) ? undefined : v));
```

Demo:

```js
let audience = {
  "label": "test",
  "id": "test",
  "styles": {
    "label": "Styles",
    "styles": {
      "test": {
        "test": "test",
        "label": "test",
        "test1": {
          "label": "test",
          "image": {
            "label": "test",
            "type": "test",
            "value": "test",
            "autoSelect": "",
            "id": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "label": "test",
    "test": []
  }
}
const removeKeys = ["label", "type", "autoSelect"];
let newAudience = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(audience, (k, v) => removeKeys.includes(k) ? undefined : v));
console.log(newAudience);
```

Along the same lines, if you're parsing the original object from a JSON string, you can use the `reviver` callback from [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
let jsonString = `{
  "label": "test",
  "id": "test",
  "styles": {
    "label": "Styles",
    "styles": {
      "test": {
        "test": "test",
        "label": "test",
        "test1": {
          "label": "test",
          "image": {
            "label": "test",
            "type": "test",
            "value": "test",
            "autoSelect": "",
            "id": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "label": "test",
    "test": []
  }
}`
const removeKeys = ["label", "type", "autoSelect"];
const audience = JSON.parse(jsonString, (k, v) => removeKeys.includes(k) ? undefined : v);
console.log(audience);
```

Comment: The downside here is that it only works with simple data types. As soon as the input data has values like `Set`, `Map`, `Date`, `RegExp`, ... etc, it will not work.

Comment: @trincot correct, this is only for values that are serializable to/from JSON. As I said, it's kind of a hack, and not the right solution for all scenarios.

Comment: Very interesting for the right scenario of objects with strict data types.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the keys and build new objects by taking an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
function remove(object, keys) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(object)
        .filter(k => !keys.includes(k))
        .map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object' ? remove(object[k], keys) : object[k] }))
    );
}

var item = { label: "test", id: "test", styles: { label: "Styles", styles: { test: { test: "test", label: "test", test1: { label: "test", image: { label: "test", type: "test", value: "test", autoSelect: "", id: "" } } } } }, test: { label: "test", test: [] } },
    removeKeys = ["label", "type", "autoSelect"];

console.log(remove(item, removeKeys));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function recursively, but you don't do anything with the result this recursive call returns. You have to overwrite the sub-key with the filtered value:

```js
let item = {
  "label": "test",
  "id": "test",
  "styles": {
    "label": "Styles",
    "styles": {
      "test": {
        "test": "test",
        "label": "test",
        "test1": {
          "label": "test",
          "image": {
            "label": "test",
            "type": "test",
            "value": "test",
            "autoSelect": "",
            "id": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "label": "test",
    "test": []
  }
}

const removeKeys = ["label", "type", "autoSelect"];

let filterObject = filterNestObject(item);

function filterNestObject(item) {
  return Object.keys(item)
    .filter(key => {
      if (typeof item[key] === 'object') {
        // set the key to the filtered result returned by the recursively called function
        item[key] = filterNestObject(item[key]);
      }

      if (!removeKeys.includes(key)) return true;

      return false
    })
    .reduce((object, key) => {
      return {
        ...object,
        [key]: item[key]
      };
    }, {});

}

console.log(filterNestObject(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `Object.entries`, `filter` + `includes`, `map`, and `Object.fromEntries` -

```
const removeDeepKeys = (keys = [], o = {}) =>
  Object (o) === o
    ? Object
        .fromEntries
          ( Object
              .entries (o)
              .filter (([ k, _ ]) => ! keys .includes (k))
              .map (([ k, v ]) => [ k, removeDeepKeys (keys, v) ])
          )
    : o
```

Try it on your `item` -

```
removeDeepKeys ([ 'label', 'type', 'autoSelect' ], item)
```

Output -

```
{
  "id": "test",
  "styles": {
    "styles": {
      "test": {
        "test": "test",
        "test1": {
          "image": {
            "value": "test",
            "id": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "test": {}
  }
}
```

---

EDIT to support arrays -

```
const removeDeepKeys = (keys = [], o = {}) =>
  Array .isArray (o)
    ? o .map (v => removeKeys (keys, v))
    : Object (o) === o
        ? Object
            .fromEntries
              ( Object
                  .entries (o)
                  .filter (([ k, _ ]) => ! keys .includes (k))
                  .map (([ k, v ]) => [ k, removeDeepKeys (keys, v) ])
              )
        : o
```